# How do I reference an object within an array within an object in xcode 8?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, object

I'm looking to try and reference all "titles" within this json ([link here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json)) in xcode 8. The issue is there's an object and array that need to be referenced (i believe) before I can pull the title data, and I'm not sure how to do that.

So far this is what i've got:

```
func fetchFeed(){
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json")!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        self.artists = [Artist]()
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

            if let feedFromJson = json["feed"]?["entry"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                for feedFromJson in feedsFromJson {
                    let feed = Feed()
                    if let entry = feedFromJson["entry"] as? String, let author = feedFromJson["domain"] as? String {

                        feed.entry = entry

                        article.headline = title

                    }
                    self.articles?.append(article)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
```

And thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working hard to try to understand what you need. If you want to get an `Article` array where the `headline` is the title label for the entry, here is how I cheated it out.

```
func articles(from json: Any?) -> [Article] {
    guard let json = json as? NSDictionary, let entries = json.value(forKeyPath: "feed.entry") as? [NSDictionary] else {
        return []
    }

    return entries.flatMap { entry in
        guard let title = entry.value(forKeyPath: "title.label") as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        var article = Article()
        article.headline = title
        return article
    }
}
```

you call it as such

```
self.articles = articles(from: json)
```

`NSDictionary` has the method `value(forKeyPath:)` that is near magic. Calling `json.value(forKeyPath: "feed.entry")` returns an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary is an `"entry"` object in the json. Next, I map each entry to call `entry.value(forKeyPath: "title.label")` which returns a string.

---

If this is something more than a quick solution, then I would consider adding [`SwiftyJSON`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to your project.

```
func articles(from json: Any?) -> [Article] {
    return JSON(json)["feed"]["entry"].arrayValue.flatMap { entry in
        guard let title = entry["title"]["label"].string else {
            return nil
        }

        var article = Article()
        article.headline = title
        return article
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right, value(forKeyPath) is godly. That solved my issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. There is two kinds of titles.
   the "feed" and the "entry".

> if let entry = feedFromJson["entry"] as? String, let author = feedFromJson["domain"] as? String {

The practice of iOS is not this.

**feedFromJson["entry"]** is nil ,not a string . I guess you try to get the "feed" title.

```
if let entry = (json["feed"] as Dictionary)?["title"]
```

To get the "entry" title. Just traverse the array, and get the title.

```
let titleDict = feedFromJson["title"] as? Dictionary
let title = titleDict["title"] as? String
article.headline = title
```

2. Better to know the structure of the JSON data.

It's too quick.

> if let feedFromJson = json["feed"]?["entry"] as? [[String :
>   AnyObject]] {

You should step by step.

```
if let feedFromJson = (json["feed"] as Dictionary)?["entry"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips Jeffery and DengApro, going to use them tonight and will let you know how it goes.

Cheers

Comment: Jeffery's method is more swift,  .flatMap is a good monad. Mine is intuitive, figure out the structure ,get the data, JSON is not hard. I also prefer SwiftyJSON .